# Простой WPF Binding. Будет ли утечка памяти?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Уважаемые гуру, прошу растолковать по привязкам. В учебных статьях "для чайников" вопросы утечек вообще не рассматриваются, а самостоятельный поиск информации по частям привел к тому, что я запутался. Что я нарыл:
Для борьбы с утечками памяти в WPF, нужно привязываться к объектам, реализующим `INotifyCollectionChanged`. Ок, в случае коллекций, все понятно. Привязываемся через `ObservableCollection`.
Но как быть с простыми типами данных?
Допустим у нас простая страничка, на которой есть текстовое поле, куда пользователь вводит свое имя. Для работы с этим именем, привяжем его к полю `name`.

View:

```
<TextBlock Text="Ваше имя:"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding name}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public string name {get; set;}
...
this.DataContext = this;
this.InitializeComponent();
```

Согласно [этой](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/938416) страницы, для борьбы с утечкой, необходимо или реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged` на объекте-источнике, либо сделать свойство `DependencyProperty`. Но я нигде не могу найти простой пример, как это правильно сделать.

---

[Тут](http://sonyks2007.blogspot.ru/2014/09/wpf-list.html), в последнем абзаце, вообще написано:

> Если вы используете .NET Framework 4.5, то у вас не будет утечки
>   памяти

Так как *правильно* реализовать привязку данных?

Comment: В практических ситуациях такая утечка возникает очень редко, у меня, например, ни разу не возникала.

Comment: @VladD Отчего это зависит? Почему у кого-то возникает, а у кого-то нет? И как правильно поступить? 1. Забить и надеяться что утечки никогда так и не возникнет? 2. Разобраться с этими `INotifyPropertyChanged` и `DependencyProperty` и использовать их всегда в таких случаях?

Comment: Написал ответ. В любом случае разобраться с INPC и DP нужно обязательно!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В документе, на которые вы ссылаетесь, написано следующее:

> This issue occurs if the following conditions are true:
>
> - A data-binding path refers to property `P` of object `X`.
> - Object `X` contains a direct reference or an indirect reference to the target of the data-binding operation.
> - Property `P` is accessed through a `PropertyDescriptor` object instead of a `DependencyProperty` object or a `PropertyInfo` object.

Из этих условий необычным является второе: «Object `X` contains a direct reference or an indirect reference to the target of the data-binding operation».

Если вы программируете с использованием MVVM, ваш объект `X` скорее всего VM-объект, а целевой элемент привязки — View-объект. В нормальной ситуации объекты VM не имеют права знать о View, и таким образом не должны содержать на него прямых или непрямых ссылок.

Значит, проблема может возникнуть только если у вас View-объект ссылается на другой View-объект. Но свойства UI-объектов обычно являются `DependencyProperty`, поэтому этот случай тоже в подавляющем большинстве случаев не имеет места.

Что нужно делать?

1. Если вы производите `Binding` UI-объекта к другому свойству UI-объекта, имеет смысл обратить внимание на то, является ли то, что вы привязываете, `DependencyProperty`. В подавляющем большинстве случаев это так и будет.
2. Если всё же оказывается, что вам кровь из носу нужно забиндить свойство одного UI-объекта на другое свойство, которое не является `DependencyProperty` (например, как в примере из статьи, которую вы привели:

   ```
   <StackPanel Name="MyStackPanel">
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MyStackPanel, Path=Children.Count}" />
   </StackPanel>
   ```

   в этом примере memory leak возникает и в VS 2015), вам нужно поменять `Binding` на `OneTime`: в этом случае всё равно вы не получаете нотификаций об изменении свойства (т. к. `INotifyPropertyChanged` не реализовано, и свойство не есть `DependencyProperty`).
3. Более прагматичный подход — не парьтесь с каждой привязкой, тестируйте ваше приложение при помощи memory profiler'а, и если обнаружите утечку памяти, описанную в статье, почините её как указано в п. 2.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Прочитав несколько раз, начал понимать. Для полной ясности, мне не хватает понимания: 1. Правильно ли я понимаю, что в контексте Вашего ответа `View-объект` == `UI-объект`, а все они вместе - это любой `FrameworkElement`? 2. Выходит, что правильный ответ на вопрос "Будет ли утечка памяти?" с тем кодом, что в моем вопросе - "Нет"?

Comment: @user200141: (1) Да, но не обязательно `FrameworkElement`: например, `StackPanel.Children` может быть просто `IList` или чем-то наподобие. Имеются в виду объекты UI-layer'а. (2) Если у вас нет ссылок из `DataContext`'а назад в UI, то верно.

Comment: Простите недостаток моих знаний, никак не могу понять/нагуглить выражение (2). Я понял, если я привяжусь ровно так, как написал в вопросе, то все ОК. Если я сошлюсь из VM через x:Name как-то так: `MyTextBox.Text = someDefaultTextVariable`, то память утечет?

Comment: @user200141: Ну, code-behind контрола или окна — это не VM, это тот же самый View-layer. То, к чему у вас происходит `Binding` — это объект из другого layer'а, который не должен ничего знать, о View.

Comment: Вот это поворот :) Я вижу мне еще учиться и учиться. Спасибо за объяснение. По крайней мере ответ на свой вопрос мне ясен теперь.

Comment: @user200141: Почитайте про MVVM обязательно, без него никак. Ну и у нас тут было много вопросов по тегу [tag:mvvm].